# background image slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a navigation that has a background image slide effect and I'm trying to imitate a website's design: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/BeautifulBackgroundImageNavigation/

However, since I intend to do the effect for the phone with the size of 480*800, so I need to change the size of the elements and this seems a problem since I want to do exactly as what the website designs but there are still differences. I have already put in http://jsfiddle.net/u4mLdojo/

The main problem is with sub1, sub2 and sub3, which are supposed to be invisible unless they are clicked, but I don't know why they stick with the page.

```
<ul class="sub1" style="background-position:0 0;">
<ul class="sub2" style="background-position:-100px 0;">
<ul class="sub3" style="background-position:-100px 0;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use this library: https://github.com/nelsonwellswku/jquery.bgpos/

Here is all the code in a nice jsbin playground:

http://jsbin.com/duresilutu/2/edit?output